# My data from node did not bind to template variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express

When i have tryied to deploy my simple nodejs blog app on Heroku I have very strage error. My data from node did not bind to template variables.
So I have right work app local [image]

But after deploy on Heroku there is an error in action name that based on the name that I take from server and add to template variables. Here is wrong image and code.[image]

Controllers code

```
exports.new  = function(req, res) {
  res.render('users/new', {
    user: new User({}),
    action:'/create'
  });
};
```

form code

extends base

```
block content
  - var action = action || '/users'
  if (!user.isNew)
    - action += '/'+user.id

  form(action=action, method='post')
    if(!user.isNew)
      input(type='hidden', name='_method', value='put')

    p
      label Name
        br
        input.input(name='name', type='text', value=user.name)

    p
      label Username
        br
        input(name='username', type='text', value=user.username)

    p
      label Email
        br
        input(name='email', type='text', value=user.email)

    p
      label Change password
        br
        input(name='password', type='password', placeholder='Type a new one to update')

    p
      button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Save user
```

new template code

```
extends form

block prepend content
  h2 New user
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

It think can be cache problem.

Try to make some changes in controller file (ex. add some new variable when rendering "users/new" template). Also, try to re-deploy app.